# Fazer um Shell Script bash que extraia para um novo ficheiro todos nomes e nr de mulheres cujo número comece por "91"

Tags: linux, script, shell, bash

Considere que existe um ficheiro "ficheiro1.txt" que tem por exemplo:

Nome da pessoa;Sexo;Codigo Postal;Numero Telemovel;Marca do Telemovel 
...

Como faço para escrever um shell script bash que extraia para um novo ficheiro todos os nomes e números de telemovel de todas as pessoas de sexo feminino cujo numero de telemovel começa por "93".

Se alguem souber agradeço.

Comment: Pode adicionar exemplos das linhas desse arquivo?

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma e que você pode adaptar em outros casos, seria usando o **awk**.

```
cat ficheiro1.txt|awk -F ";" '{if (($2 == "Feminino") && ($4 ~ /^93/)) print $1,$4}' > novoficheiro.txt
```

Destrinchando o comando:

**cat ficheiro1.txt |** = Joga o conteúdo do arquivo para ser tratado no awk

**awk -F ";"** = Separa as colunas do seu arquivo em campos($1,$2,$3...) usando como delimitador o ;

**'{if (($2 == "Feminino") && ($4 ~ "93"))** = Cria uma condição em que a segunda coluna($2) vai ser positiva se tiver a palavra "Feminino" e se a quarta coluna($4) começar com "93".

Nesse momento o programa filtrou todas as linhas e só restaram as que contêm a palavra "Feminino" na coluna dois e que a coluna do telefone comece com "93".

**print $1,$4}' > novoficheiro.txt** =  Imprime em um arquivo apenas as colunas do nome e do telefone.

Comment: Cool (+1) já agora uma rápida simpilifcaçao: `awk -F";" '$2 == "Feminino" && $4 ~ /^93/ { print $1,$4}'  file.txt > out.txt`

Comment: Boa! Nem sabia dessa simplificação do If no awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat ficheiro1.txt | grep '^[^;]*;Feminino;[^;]*;93' | cut -d ';' -f 1,4 > saida.txt
```

Quebrando:

```
grep '^[^;]*;Feminino;[^;]*;93'
```

É uma expressão regular que ignora o *Nome da pessoa*, casa com **Feminino**, ignora o *Código Postal* e finalmente casa com *Números de telefone móvel* que iniciem com **93**

```
cut -d ';' -f 1,4 > saida.txt
```

Separamos a linha em colunas delimitadas pelo **;**  e escolhemos a primeira e a quarta coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Somente `awk` v1:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{if($2=="Feminino" && index($4,"93")==1) print $1,$4}' ficheiro1.txt
```

Somente `awk` v2:

```
$ awk -F";" '$2=="Feminino" && $4~/^93/ {print $1,$4}' ficheiro1.txt
```

Utilizando `grep` e `cut`:

```
$ grep '^[^;]*;Feminino;[^;]*;93' ficheiro1.txt | cut -d ';' -f 1,4
```